# how to create md5 or sha1 checksum of a file without loading its contents to memory?

Tags: c++, winapi, md5, checksum, sha

I mean similar thing like in php `sha1_file`.

I found very nice and compact script that does not need external libraries like boost : http://code.google.com/p/smallsha1/source/browse/trunk/sha1.cpp

But is there a way to pass to it a file stream when the file is for example 10GB in size ?

Comment: These are incremental hashes, so you read in a chunk of the file, update the context, read in the next chunk...

Answer (score 5):

That exact code can't take a stream, no.

Look at the loop `while (currentBlock <= endOfFullBlocks)`. It runs 64 bytes at a time through the actual hashing code. So in order to modify this code to take a stream, you need it to read those 64 bytes from the stream rather than taking them from `sarray` (which points to the same data as the input `src`).

64 bytes per read is *not* an efficient way to read 10GB of data, so actually you might like to introduce a second loop: one to read larger chunks from the file and one to put 64 byte blocks of that through the hash.

You will of course also need to modify the code to handle the "leftover" part of the input data that's not a multiple of 64.

Alternatively, find a different SHA1 implementation with "init", "update", "finish"/"digest" functions, and use that instead. The idea of such interfaces is that you call "update" as many times as you like, passing in chunks of data of whatever size is convenient for reading your stream.

Answer (score 0):

For large files you can memory map part of the file, calculate sum, remap to the next part of the file and continue summing, and so on.